# The watch command with shell not recognizing filenames

Tags: command-line, bash, watch-command

While trying `watch bash -c 'du -h /etc/passwd && df -h'` it appears that the path to file was completely ignored, and instead `du -h` ran through the current working directory. Same result was observed when I ran `watch bash -c 'stat /etc/passwd && df -h'`, and `stat` returned with `stat: missing operand` error. By contrast, using `watch -e "command /path/to/file"` or `watch "command /path/to/file"` works without issues.

Why doesn't `watch bash -c 'du -h /etc/passwd && df -h'` work then ? Is it `watch`'s issue or `bash`'s issue with argument splitting ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`watch` executes commands with arguments by passing them to `sh -c`, so what you end up running is:

```
sh -c 'bash -c du -h /etc/passwd && df -h'
```

The shell you're running removes the first layer of quotes you applied.
The `-h`, `/etc/passwd` are then passed as `$0` and `$1` to bash, so they're effectively ignored. Run something like:

```
watch 'du -h /etc/passwd && df -h'
watch "bash -c 'du -h /etc/passwd && df -h'"
```

To verify, using `strace`:

```
strace -fe execve -o log watch bash -c 'du -h /etc/passwd && df -h'
```

And `log` contains:

```
17132 execve("/usr/bin/watch", ["watch", "bash", "-c", "du -h /etc/passwd && df -h"], [/* 40 vars */]) = 0
17134 execve("/bin/sh", ["sh", "-c", "bash -c du -h /etc/passwd && df "...], [/* 42 vars */]) = 0
17135 execve("/bin/bash", ["bash", "-c", "du", "-h", "/etc/passwd"], [/* 42 vars */]) = 0
17135 execve("/usr/bin/du", ["du"], [/* 42 vars */]) = 0
17135 +++ exited with 0 +++
```

Comment: So effectively,  `du` becomes `$0` and that's why it runs, however, `df` is supposed to become of positional parameters to `bash` right ?   or does `sh -c` already separate them when `&&` is encountered ?

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy `-h` will be $0. Yes, the `&&` separates them, this is just like running `bash -c du -h /etc/passwd && df -h` directly in the shell (note lack of quotes).

Comment: yep, you're right, in -c parameters are shifted, quoteception got me confused